# How to attach a file when creating document

Tags: node.js, domino-appdev-pack

We can use database.createDocument() to create new document into Domino with certain data type (text, number, datetime, and reference). How can I create new document if that document has file attachment?

I tried to create new document with a file as one of the attribute, and it produce error *Cannot convert document. Unknown item type: file*

Answer (score 1):

With the next version (1.0.2) of the appdev pack, you'll be able to handle attachments on a document.  There will be more support for these kinds of operations in future versions as well.